Add default text to curses Textbox object
I'm using the curses python library in an application and have implemented a Textbox as well https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#textbox-objects.
Is there a way to add a default text when displaying the text box that can then be either edited or replaced by the user?
Example of textbox usage:
import curses
import curses.textpad

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.addstr(1, 0, "Text: ")
    stdscr.refresh()
    
    win = curses.newwin(1, 20, 1, 6)
    textbox = curses.textpad.Textbox(win)

    # add a default text here to be displayed
    # which can be modified, deleted or replaced
    text = textbox.edit()
    
    stdscr.addstr(3, 0, "Input: ")
    stdscr.addstr(3, 7, text)
    stdscr.refresh()

    stdscr.getch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)


do you want a textbox or a dialog box ? , to add to a textbox (a bounded area of the 'screen') a call such as screen.addstr( x pos , y pos, "your text here" ) is all that's required, but i'm not 100% sure that's what you want. post a minimal working example of your code to avoid any ambiguities

A simple addstr(...) on the win actually seems to work!

not 100% convinced your example does what you expect,
here's a rudimentary example that prompts and captures the input.
import curses

def main(stdscr):

    stdscr.clear()

    stdscr.addstr(10, 10, "Your answer here : ")

    curses.echo() # so we can see what's being entered
    user_input = stdscr.getstr(10, 30).decode('utf-8')

    stdscr.addstr(12, 10, f"You entered: {user_input}")

    stdscr.addstr(14, 10, f"press a key to quit:")
    stdscr.getch()

# init
curses.wrapper(main)


hope this helps
